# Visual studio 2015 Android Emulator

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I created a Xamarin project in VS 2015.

But I don't see any option to run the project into device emulator.

I only see list of unsupported devices.

[image]

How can I run my xamarin application in device emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see any supported device try to set your API lower (API 19), or try to create new device in AVD Menager (it's intuitive) here you have a tutorial [Creating an Android Emulator](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/android/en/creating_an_android_emulator.html).

Remember some machines work on x86, but some on ARM architecture select appropriate one.

Or maybe you are looking for this:[Visual studio emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/)? Microsoft's emulator is much faster. In my opinion is also more comfortable.